# Outputting Specific Prosperities of an Array(List) of Objects in Python

Tags: python

I have an class Student which has an array(list) of Objects called Students. I am trying to output the names of all the students in the array.

```py
class Student(object):
    name = ""
    age = 0
    major = ""

    # The class "constructor" - It's actually an initializer 
    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major

Students = []

Students.append(Student("Dave",23,"Chem"))
Students.append(Student("Emma",34,"Maths"))
Students.append(Student("Alex",19,"Art"))

print(Students[0].__dict__)
print(Students[1].__dict__)
print (Students[0])
```

Both the ways I have found and tired do not output the specific name but the location or the whole object. Is there a way to just output the name? For example output Students[0] name Dave

````
{'name': 'Emma', 'age': 34, 'major': 'Maths'}
<__main__.Student object at 0x000001FCDE4C2FD0>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the name, you can `print(Students[0].name)`. If you want to see the relevant attributes when printing a `Student` object, you can implement the `__repr__` method.

```py
class Student:

    # The class "constructor" - It's actually an initializer 
    def __init__(self, name, age, major):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.major = major

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Student name={self.name} age={self.age} major={self.major}>"
```

This way you can simply do `print(Students[0])` to see the name, age and major of a student.

By the way, for a normal class definition, you want to initialize instance attributes inside the `__init__` method, instead of declaring them above `__init__`: those are class attributes. Please read [this section of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) to familiarize yourself with the syntax.